# Why is there "no matching function" for my call to mem_fun_ref?

Tags: c++, inheritance, binding, virtual-functions, overriding

I have some code where classes inherit from a base class.

That base class has a function which, when run, ought to call functions to be implemented by the children. That is, the general algorithm is the same for all children, but the implementation of the steps should vary.

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(T y):y(y) { for(int i; i < 10; ++i) x.push_back(i); };
    protected:
        virtual bool IsOk(T, int)=0;
        void Run()
        {
            vector<int>::iterator it, bound;
            for(int i; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                cout << "step " << i << endl;
                bound = partition(x.begin(), x.end(), bind2nd(mem_fun_ref(&Foo<T>::IsOk), i));
                for (it=x.begin(); it!=bound; ++it)
                    cout << "  " << *it;
            };
        };
    private:
        vector<int>x;
        T y;
};

class Bar : public Foo<int>
{
    public:
        Bar():Foo<int>(50){this->Run();};
        bool IsOk(int x , int y) {return x == y;}

};
```

However, when I do so, I get the following error message :
`no matching function for call to 'mem_fun_ref(bool (Foo<int>::*)(int, int))'`

Could anyone provide me with some insight as to what I am doing wong?

Comment: where is the defition of `'mem_fun_ref(bool (Foo<int>::*)(int, int))` can you show us that?

Comment: @Als: `mem_fun_ref` is a standard library function.

Comment: @Space: Yes, just checked! My bad.

Comment: What you've described (main function calls virtual methods, which descendants override to customize the details) is known as the *template method pattern*, although in a C++ context, the name can be a little confusing since it doesn't actually refer to C++ templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the prorotypes for `mem_fun_ref`

```
template <class S, class T>
  mem_fun_ref_t<S,T> mem_fun_ref (S (T::*f)());

template <class S, class T, class A>
  mem_fun1_ref_t<S,T,A> mem_fun_ref (S (T::*f)(A));

template <class S, class T>
  const_mem_fun_ref_t<S,T> mem_fun_ref (S (T::*f)() const);

template <class S, class T, class A>
  const_mem_fun1_ref_t<S,T,A> mem_fun_ref (S (T::*f)(A) const);
```

Your `mem_fun_ref(bool (Foo<int>::*)(int, int))` dosnt match any of these & hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

`mem_fun_ref` only works for functions taking one or no argument. To implement what you have in mind you will have to use [`boost::bind`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html) (part of the standard library in C++0x).